# How to parse image from browser post

Tags: html, image, jsp, amazon-s3

I’m trying to capture image data posted to a JSP page in order to send it to AWS using their S3 PutObject API.  I have a JSP web app and when a client browser uploads a selected image file, I want to capture the data on the back end via a JSP page GetImage and parse it so I can send just the image to AWS' S3.  Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE - I found that when a form has enctype="multipart/form-data" the form data is sent via the data stream.  In there, the contents are delineated with the field name and data.  It looks like the image data is encoded base 64. I'm now looking to find how to parse the fields and data.

```
<html>  
    <body>
    
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm" action="GetImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
            <fieldset>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="test" accept=".jpg,.png,.tif,.gif">
                </div>
            
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Post</button>
                    
            </fieldset>
        
        </form>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm

Comment: You said that a data is posted to JSP, but it's not the action attribute. Post actual code.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for the link but that show's how to send a file, I'm looking at the receiving end processing.  It turns out the file is encoded in the request's data stream on a post with a enc type multipart

Comment: @glez — Try reading past the first 1/4 which explains how to write the form and get to the JSP part that takes up the bulk of the article.

Comment: For reading and parsing that worked fine.  Rather than writing to a local file, I grabbed the input stream and captured the data to send to AWS.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out the file data is encoded in the request's data stream on a post from a form with a encType multipart/form-data.  To read the raw posted file you have to read the data stream and then parse the field entries.  Look for Name, Content-type, Filename, etc.

Here's the simplified code I came up with.  This will return ALL field items including the contents of a file (in value field).

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*;

// Parses HTML forms with type "multipart/form-data"
public static class MultipartParam
{
    public String fieldName = "";
    public String value     = "";
    public String type      = "";
    public String fileName  = "";
    public long   fileLen   = 0;
}
    
public static void parseMultipartHtml(HttpServletRequest request, ArrayList<MultipartParam> paramList) throws Exception
{
    // Verify the content type
    String contentType = request.getContentType();

    if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0))
    {
        // Create a new file upload handler
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        
        // Process file items
        List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
        
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();

            
            MultipartParam aParam = new MultipartParam();
            paramList.add(aParam);

            
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            aParam.fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            aParam.fileName  = fi.getName();
            aParam.fileLen   = fi.getSize();
            aParam.type      = fi.getContentType();
            aParam.value     = fi.getString();
        }
    }
}
```